# How to use Susy for Static Layouts?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, susy

I am struggling to learn Susy and building responsive pages with it. Prior to Susy I have been using Bootstrap grid and have gotten used to designing web pages using that Grid. When I design in Bootstrap Grid I know the exact with of the columns and use images of that size accordingly. For example an image that spans 3 columns will be 270px wide. The concept that I am struggling to learn with Susy is how to determine the width of my images according to the number of columns it takes.

In short I want to stick to my old technique of using static widths but instead of Bootstrap grid, use Susy.

Has anyone else also faced the same problem? Or am I missing some concept?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I figured it out. This is the configuration I used to mimic the Bootstrap Grid.

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,        
    column-width: 70px,
    gutters:30px/70px,  
    debug: (image: show)
);
```

This generates exactly the grid used by Bootstrap